# Use Firefox as default browser, but open links in Chrome from a specific program

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, firefox, browser, url

I use this IRC client mIRC and sometimes people post links there, you never know what's there, so I use Chrome as backup browser for all the mess that comes to computer. But in daily use of internet I use Firefox.

So e.g. Use Firefox to open links from any other program when clicked on link, like Thunderbird and etc.

But when you click on a link on mIRC, it should open it on Chrome only.

Is this possible?

Comment: Chrome is far from bulletproof, don t think that because you open the link in chrome, that mean you re safe. If the link is suspicious, boot a VM, and open the link inside the VM, not on your PC!

Comment: Browsers aren't bulletproof in general. If you're concerned about security, then VM is a better solution. If you just want to keep your history/cache clean, you should rather use incognito/private mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's your operating system? There's [Browser Chooser](http://browserchooser.codeplex.com/) for **Windows**
 and [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/) for **Apple OS X**.